# Predicate calculus "Gold and silver ornaments are precious".please check.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

> "Gold and silver ornaments are precious".
>
> The following notations are used $:$
>
> $G(x):x$ is a gold ornament
>
> $S(x):x$ is a silver ornament
>
> $P(x):x$ is precious
>
> Options are $:$
>
> 1. $\forall x(P(x) \implies (G(x) \wedge S(x)))$
> 2. $\forall x((G(x) \wedge S(x)) \implies P(x))$
> 3. $\exists x((G(x) \wedge S(x)) \implies P(x))$
> 4. $\forall x((G(x) \vee S(x)) \implies P(x))$

---

I try to explain $:$ At the same time an ornament can not be gold and silver , it should be either gold are silver , therefore option $(4)$ is correct .

---

> Please check whether my solution is correct ?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Please check whether my solution is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct .

Basically statement is saying that for every thing, if it is a Gold ornament or a silver ornament, then it is precious. So ,

> $\forall x((G(x) \vee S(x)) \implies P(x))$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the interpretation of "and" in natural language(s that I know) is that between nouns or pronouns they should be interpreted as the conjunction of the statements formed by keeping each noun/pronoun.

For example this means that "Gold and silver ornaments are precious" should be interpreted as $\textrm{"Gold ornaments are precious"} \land \textrm{"Silver ornaments are precious"}$.

Furthermore "Gold ornaments are precious" means that if something is a "Gold ornament" then it's "Precious" (and as not qualified this is supposed to hold universally).

This boils down to it being the same as $(\forall x G(x)\rightarrow P(x)) \land (\forall x S(x)\rightarrow P(x))$ which is equivalent to 4.

That 4 is not equivalent to any of the other is simple predicate calculus that's left as an excercise.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.